# Looking for open source gui components for audio controls in java

Tags: java, user-interface, audio

I need fairly simple audio analyzer gui components for audio playback where I can view different channels, control channel gain, see simple audio waveforms, etc.

I know I'm wording this horribly, so have a look at these screenshots for the kind of things I need:

[examples](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/25-free-digital-audio-editors/)

Are there any open-source gui frameworks for audio projects available?

Comment: Well in Processing.org, that can be used as a library from a Java code, there is [minim](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/) that can make this things you need. Don't know if it is a good path to you tough...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a specific project for so, but maybe you can use something from other projects.

The [Tarsos project](https://github.com/JorenSix/Tarsos) is a project led by a musician and a computer scientist for sound analysis in Java. It contains some swing elements to draw waveforms, which you could try to use in your own project. Some of the stuff they have:

- The [WaveForm](https://github.com/JorenSix/Tarsos/blob/master/src/be/hogent/tarsos/ui/WaveForm.java) class, which seems to handle some GUI stuff regarding wave form, like scaling and playing a selection part.
- [CommandPanel](https://github.com/JorenSix/Tarsos/blob/master/src/be/hogent/tarsos/ui/pitch/CommandPanel.java), which uses JSlider. You could use theses for channel gain.

There is also the [Java Media Component/Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html), which seems to provide some [audio/video related stuff](http://grack.com/downloads/school/enel619.10/report/java_media_framework.html) (rather old article) to GUI programming. It seems to be better supported in JavaFX, but [this guy](http://www.matthicks.com/2009/05/java-media-components-jmc-in-swing.html) managed to use it in a Swing application. [This guy](http://vsathishkumar.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/java-media-components/) show some code using JMC too.

In the page you sent, there is the [Eisenkraut](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eisenkraut), which is made in Java. You could try to reuse some of its components.

Comment: thanks! I'm currently investigating the source code for Eisenkraut. Keeping my fingers crossed.